# Button Command между двумя ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

У меня есть главное окно программы и UserControl, пытаюсь сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку присвоить Visibility Grid'у, Grid находится в главном окне. Если в главном окне я могу присвоить Visibility, а вот как при нажатии кнопки в UserControl присвоить Visibility Grid'у главного окна.

Grid:

```
<Grid Grid.RowSpan="2" Visibility="{Binding visibilitySendMessage, Mode=TwoWay}">


public Visibility visibilitySendMessage { get; set; } = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Из UserControl:

```
<MenuItem Header="Написать"  Command="{Binding DataContext.CommandSendMessage, Source={x:Reference data}}"
```

CommandSendMessage = new RelayCommand(() => viewModel.visibilitySendMessage = Visibility.Visible);

Comment: У вас это Visibility к чему-то привязано?

Comment: Андрей NOP, да.

Comment: Grid Grid.RowSpan="2" Visibility="{Binding visibilitySendMessage, Mode=TwoWay}"            
public Visibility visibilitySendMessage { get; set; } = Visibility.Collapsed;

Comment: Значит корневая VM должна как-то передать информацию о том что нужно сделать в дочернюю VM, например, команду можно создать в корневой VM, либо можно передать делегат параметром

Comment: Андрей NOP, например у меня в корневой VM есть команда, но я не понимаю как передать ее в дочерную

Comment: Да как угодно — параметром конструктора или напрямую записать в свойство.